# Having a hard time installing pip on my Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-7

I'm using Python 3.8.0 on my WIN 7 32-bit, but the problem is that I can't install pip on my computer. At first, that was not the case, I'd actually got installed on my pc, but it couldn't install any package with "pip install [package name]".
In both cases it did return the same error, I've already tried installing different versions of Python, on different folders, downloading get-pip.py and installing manually, but the same happened.

The error presents: https://pastebin.com/u75NpdfK

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\get-pip.py", line 22318, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\get-pip.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6ny94zvj\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6ny94zvj\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6ny94zvj\pip.zip\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6ny94zvj\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6ny94zvj\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6ny94zvj\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6ny94zvj\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 64, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 915, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Try using `python3 -m ensurepip` to install pip

Comment: Take a look at [Install pip](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/)

Comment: Save yourself a lot of future pain.  Use the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/).

Comment: https://chocolatey.org/ is your friend, install python and pip via chocolatey,..

Comment: Thanks guys, but unfortunately none of these options worked :^(

Answer (score 0):

This error "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" occurs when you failed to close a file in os(since the file is already closed ).So it throws a error .Try after clearing a temp files.If not working after that kindly let me know the solution.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip, unfortunately it didn't work